# How can I see the SQL executed during an Ecto test?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When running an Ecto test with `mix test ...`, the SQL executed is not shown. As far as I can tell, it is not logged to any file, either. How can I see it? (I am using Ecto as part of a Phoenix application.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ecto logs the SQL queries with the level `:debug`. By default, the Logger level is set to `:warn` in `config/test.exs`, which will completely ignore `:debug` level logs. You can lower the level to `:debug` to see the SQL queries executed by Ecto. In `config/test.exs`, change:

```
config :logger, level: :warn
```

to

```
config :logger, level: :debug
```

and then run `mix test`.

You can also change the level with which Ecto logs the queries by following the `:loggers` instructions [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html).

Comment: Thank you! I found the logger settings in `config/` but somehow didn't spot that it was different in the `test` environment, so I thought something more complicated was happening...

Comment: @dogbert for some reason I still see no queries, any other thoughts as to what I may have to do? Or why queries wouldn't show up? I am working with an umbrella app and have tried running a specific test from the top level, a specific test from within a sub app, the entire suite from the top level, etc etc. I am at a loss of ideas!

Comment: Oh, it turns out we were setting ExUnit to capture logs on start, `ExUnit.start/1` takes a list of options which can include `:capture_log`, setting that to false (well that's the default, so just removing the manual setting of it to true) worked. You can also override it on a per test basis with `@tag capture_log: false`

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn on debug level just for one test by placing the following line within a test. This is useful for a quick check.

```
test "..." do
  Logger.configure(level: :debug)
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ran into the issue of still not seeing them even after setting the logger level to `:debug`, it may be that you have configured `ExUnit` to `capture_log`s (likely passed to `start/1`)